# ssh keys: which is for whom and where are they supposed to be?

Tags: ssh-keys

Having read about SSH key generation and installation, I am very confused by the idea, which I might have mistakenly gathered from all of the information: it is that a private key leaves the system on which it has been generated.

I will lay out my understanding. Please correct me where I am wrong:

1. On a host where SSH server runs I run `ssh-keygen`, and it generates `id-rsa` and `id-rsa.pub` for the current user.
2. That current user becomes enabled for a remote login authenticated by the keys generated in #1.
3. I take `id-rsa` from #1 and copy it onto the filesystem of a host where an SSH client runs.
4. I register the file from #3 in an SSH client.

This sounds different from traditional asymmetric key encryption, where a private key never leaves the system that does the decryption. Why is there only one private key and why does it need to be installed both on a server and on a client? And which software: SSH server or SSH client is the public key used?

Comment: The only thing you should ever do is copy the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to the remote system you want access to. So if you have locally run `ssh-keygen` and want to connect to a host like `example1.com`, you would go onto `example1.com`, make sure an `~/.ssh` directory exists in the user directory you want to login to. If not? Run `mkdir .ssh` and set the permissions of that directory like this: `chmod 700`. Then make sure the file `authorized_keys` exists in that `~/.ssh` directory (`~/.ssh/authorized_keys`) and just append the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to the end of that file. (1/2)

Comment: If `authorized_keys` doesn't ’t exist, create it with a text editor like this: `nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (using Nano, but the basic concept works for VI or Emacs) and simply add the contents of `id_rsa.pub` to the `authorized_keys` file. Save it and set the permissions of that file like this: `chmod 600`. Now you will be able to pass wordlessly login from your local system to `example1.com`. And do the same for `example2.com`, `example3.com` and so on. That's it! (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

> Why is there only one private key and why does it need to be installed both on a server and on a client?

To start with, **it doesn't** need to be installed both on a server and on a client. There is no reason for you to run `ssh-keygen` or copy the "private" id_rsa file anywhere else but the SSH client system.

There are actually two private keys involved – one is your "user" keypair that you've generated with `ssh-keygen` just now, the other is the server's "host" keypair which it stores in `/etc/ssh`. (The host keypair was generated at SSH server installation time – it is not per-user.)

But there's no conceptual reason why there couldn't be just one keypair, as neither of them is used for asymmetric encryption — they're only used for *signing:*

1. SSH traffic is encrypted using a symmetric algorithm (such as AES) — fresh symmetric encryption keys are negotiated for each connection using DH or ECDH key-exchange protocols. (Neither the client's nor the server's asymmetric keys are used in the process; the client might not even have one at all.)
2. The server uses its "host" keypair to identify itself to the client (that's the fingerprint you're asked to verify upon connecting for the first time) and to sign the results of the previous symmetric-key exchange.
3. Later during the user login process, the client uses your "user" keypair to identify you by making its own signature using your `id_rsa` private key, which the server then verifies against the corresponding public key stored in its `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of ssh is wrong (and your general understanding of public/private keys is correct), likely because someone was generating a key pair on a different machine to where they were going to be used - its not uncommon for this bad practice to occur.

ssh-keygen creates both public and private keys.

The public key ( `id_rsa.pub` ) is added to the remote system - it is typically added to `/path/to/userhomedir/.ssh/authorized_keys` file - 1 public key per line.

The `id_rsa` file is your private key and is not distributed.

`id_rsa.pub` can be given to anyone and widely published.

The remote system does not require an id_rsa or id_rsa.pub in the user's home directory to allow the user to log in. It only requires it if it is the client to another server.  There is another set of host keys (normally in /etc/ssh) used to prevent MITM attacks after the first negotiation, and these are typically automatically generated and not something you need to worry about.